# How to get POST parameter in JAX-RS method?

Tags: java, rest, post, parameters, jax-rs

I am developing RESTful services with Jersey and it works great with `GET` methods. But I can only get `null` parameters using the `POST` method. Here is the sample code from my project.

#### HTML

```xml
<form action="rest/console/sendemail" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

#### Java

```java
@POST
@Path("/sendemail")
public Response sendEmail(@QueryParam("email") String email) {
    System.out.println(email);
    return  new Response();
}
```

The email I get from the post is always null.
Anyone has the idea?

I changed QueryParam to FormParam, the parameter I get is still null.

Answer (score 39):

In a form submitted via `POST`, `email` is *not* a `@QueryParam` like in `/sendemail?email=me@example.com`.

If you submit your HTML `form` via `POST`, `email` is a `@FormParam`.

**Edit:**

This is a minimal JAX-RS Resource that can deal with your HTML form.

```
package rest;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/console")
public class Console {

    @POST
    @Path("/sendemail")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response sendEmail(@FormParam("email") String email) {
        System.out.println(email);
        return Response.ok("email=" + email).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 though it is strictly only true for form encoding; if the submitted document was coming as XML, you'd want to just deserialize that to be an object (of some class) _without_ any annotation that parameter.

Comment: @DonalFellows True. But in the scope of this question, we can safely assume that `@FormParam` works.

Comment: @Tichodroma, I changed QueryParam to FormParam, the parameter I get is still null.

Comment: @Tichodroma Thanks for your great help. But I use you code above, the email is still null. Any other issue leads to this?

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes, I checked the path, they are all fine. And the response page shows "email=null", it means the path is right, but I can not get the parameter sent by post method. If I changed it to get method, it works fine.

Comment: Well, the code in my answer works on GlassFish with Jersey. I have no further idea.

Comment: OK, I just use jetty server. I have no idea about it. Thanks for your  help.

Comment: You have missed the @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") annotation.

Comment: sat has the answer to this question I believe. Should put it in an answer instead of the above comment. One additional recommendation is to use the constant javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED instead of the hard coded string literal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note one small detail - every input value you want to submit as part of your form has to have "name" attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
```